# Normalizer of a Lie group

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, normal-subgroups

Let us consider a Lie subgroup $H$ of a Lie group $G$. The *Normalizer* of $H$ in $G$ is given by
$$N_{G}(H) := \{ g \in G \ : \ g^{-1} \cdot h \cdot g \in H , \ \forall h \in H\}$$

We know that $N_{G}(H)$ is a subgroup of $G$. However, without assuming that $H$ is closed in $G$,

Is N_{G}(H) a Lie subgroup of $G$?

In other words, does $N_{G}(H)$ inherit the *differentiable structure* from $H$?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $H$ is connected.

Firstly, we will show that if a Lie group $G$ acts on a smooth manifold $X$, than for every $x$ in $X$, the stabilizer
$$
\text{Stab}_{G}(x) = \{g \in G \mid g \cdot x = x\}
$$
is a Lie subgroup of $G$. Indeed, consider the map $f_x \colon G \to X$, $f_x(g) = g \cdot x$. We have $\text{Stab}_{G}(x) = f_x^{-1}(x)$. To see that $f_x$ has constant rank, pick some $g \in G$ and consider the following commutative diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
G @>{L_g}>> G\\
@VV{f_x}V @VV{f_x}V \\
X @>{g\cdot }>> X
\end{CD}$$
where $L_g(h) = gh$. Since $L_g$ and $g\cdot $ are diffeomorphisms $f_x$ has a constant rank, and by the submersion theorem, the preimage $f_x^{-1}(x)$ is an embedded submanifold and, hence, Lie subgroup.

It would be nice to act on a set of all subgroups by conjugation and say that the normalizer $N_G(H)$ is a stabilizer of $H$. Unfortunately, it is problematic to define a smooth structure on it. The idea is to use Lie algebras instead.

Let $\mathfrak{h}$ and $\mathfrak{g}$ be the corresponding Lie algebras. The group $G$ act on $\mathfrak{g}$ via the adjoint representation. For $\xi \in \mathfrak{g}$:
$$
g \cdot \xi = \text{Ad}_g (\xi) = d_e C_g (\xi) \text{, where } C_g(h) = ghg^{-1}.
$$
This action can be naturally extended to the action on $GL(\mathfrak{g})$ and, therefore, to the action on the Grassmannian $\text{Gr}_k(\mathfrak{g})$, where $k = \dim \mathfrak{h}$. My claim is:
$$
N_G(H) = \text{Stab}_G(\mathfrak{h}) = \{g \in G \mid \forall \xi \in \mathfrak{h} : g \cdot \xi \in \mathfrak{h}\}
$$
Indeed, let $g \in N_G(H)$; we have $C_g \colon H \to H$. Than $d_e C_g \colon \mathfrak{h} \to \mathfrak{h}$, which means $g \in \text{Stab}_G(\mathfrak{h})$.

On the other hand, let $g \in \text{Stab}_G(\mathfrak{h})$. For every $h \in H$, we want to show that $ghg^{-1} = C_g(h) \in H$. Since $H$ is connected(!), it is generated by the neighborhood of unity, where the exponential map is a diffeomorphism. For every $h \in H$, we obtain:
$$
C_g(h) = C_g(h_1h_2\dots h_m)
$$
where $h_i = \text{exp}(\xi_i)$ for some $\xi_i \in \mathfrak{h}$. It is obvious that $C_g$ is a group homomorphism. We have:
$$ C_g(\text{exp}(\xi_1)\text{exp}(\xi_2)\dots\text{exp}(\xi_m)) = C_g(\text{exp}(\xi_1))C_g(\text{exp}(\xi_2))\dots C_g(\text{exp}(\xi_m)) 
$$
By the following commutative diagram:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
G @>{C_g}>> G\\
@AA{\text{exp}}A @AA{\text{exp}}A \\
\mathfrak{g} @>{\text{Ad}_g }>> \mathfrak{g}
\end{CD}
$$
we have $C_g(\text{exp}(\xi_i)) = \text{exp}(\text{Ad}_g(\xi_i))$. But $g$ in stabilizer and so $\text{Ad}_g (\xi_i) \in \mathfrak{h}$, which means $\text{exp}(\text{Ad}_g (\xi_i)) \in H$. Finally:
$$
C_g(h) = \text{exp}(\text{Ad}_g(\xi_1)) \text{exp}(\text{Ad}_g(\xi_2)) \dots \text{exp}(\text{Ad}_g(\xi_m)) \in H.
$$
And we are done.